# Nodejs extract all ipAddress from a log file

Tags: javascript, node.js

There is a log file generated in my application.need to read the file and extract all the ip address from the file. The programming language i am using is Nodejs. the code is like below.
Not sure what i am doing wrong.

```
const fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile("sample.log", null, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error reading the file");
  } else {
    const fileData = data.toString();
    const ipRegex = /^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/gm;
    var arr = fileData.match(ipRegex);
    console.log(arr);
  }
});
```

when the log file is like below it works fine

```
10.55.20.116
10.55.20.184
10.55.20.187
10.55.20.45
10.55.20.7
```

[image]

But when the input is like below it is throwing null.

```
tcp.0: [1609172718.597749195, {"HOSTNAME":"sample-audi-lbs-1","IP":"10.55.17.231"}]
tcp.0: [1609172718.597749195, {"HOSTNAME":"sample-audi-lbs-1","IP":"10.55.17.232"}]
tcp.0: [1609172718.597749195, {"HOSTNAME":"sample-audi-lbs-1","IP":"10.55.17.233"}]
tcp.0: [1609172718.597749195, {"HOSTNAME":"sample-audi-lbs-1","IP":"10.55.17.234"}]
tcp.0: [1609172718.597749195, {"HOSTNAME":"sample-audi-lbs-1","IP":"10.55.17.235"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `^` means beginning of line and the `$` means end of line. If your entire line is just the IP address, it'll work, but if you need to be able to pluck the IP out of any part of the line, remove both of those characters. Working below:

```js
const fileData = `
tcp.0: [1609172718.597749195, {"HOSTNAME":"sample-audi-lbs-1","IP":"10.55.17.231"}]
tcp.0: [1609172718.597749195, {"HOSTNAME":"sample-audi-lbs-1","IP":"10.55.17.232"}]
tcp.0: [1609172718.597749195, {"HOSTNAME":"sample-audi-lbs-1","IP":"10.55.17.233"}]
tcp.0: [1609172718.597749195, {"HOSTNAME":"sample-audi-lbs-1","IP":"10.55.17.234"}]
tcp.0: [1609172718.597749195, {"HOSTNAME":"sample-audi-lbs-1","IP":"10.55.17.235"}]`;
const ipRegex = /((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)/gm;
var arr = fileData.match(ipRegex);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thanks @Nick that works. if i want to search for the whole object like {"HOSTNAME":"sample-audi-lbs-1","IP":"+ regex for ip means +"} how i can modify the search pattern

Comment: Would the reason to do this be because you want a stricter regular expression to be absolutely sure you're grabbing the right thing?

Comment: No ,In my application, the logs are really large. i need to match the whole object instead of just the ip address itself. It wont be in a separate line , sometimes it will be in a middle of a line

Comment: Maybe something like `const objectRegex = /({"HOSTNAME":.*"})/gm;` will do it for you?

Comment: (Trying to offer the simplest solution, but sometimes that casts too wide a net)